# post re-order on my site

Tags: posts, order

I want to re-order the post 'Make Enquiry' on my site http://ecentriconline.com/surferbeachfront/ so it appears last. Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Regards,

Comment: You've asked a few questions, and so far haven't accepted any.

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin called [Post Types Order](http://www.nsp-code.com/wordpress-plugins/post-types-order) which allow you to sort posts and pages you should try that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply backdate it. That should do it